# How many strings of length 8 formed using letters from $\{a,b,c,d\}$ contain exactly one pair of adjacent letters that are the same?

Tags: combinatorics

How many strings of length 8 formed using letters from $\{a,b,c,d\}$ contain exactly one pair of adjacent letters that are the same?

Can any kind soul give some hint?

Comment: @user1202487, PLEASE stop this wholesale editing of old posts. Each time you make an edit, you bump a newer question off the front page. PLEASE STOP!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

How many strings of length $8$ using those letters have the same first and second letters and have no other adjacent letters that are the same?

How many strings of length $8$ using those letters have the same second and third letters and have no other adjacent letters that are the same?

Answer (score 0):

First count the number of strings of length $7$ with no adjacent letters the same. We have four choices for the first letter, and three for each subsequent letter, so this is $4\times 3^6$.

Now choose one of these seven letters to be the repeated letter. So we get

$$7\times 4\times 3^6=20412$$